# How to build multiple regression for structures within array of structures in Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying to use the `regress` function:

```
b = regress(y,X);
```

However, I am having trouble getting it to work with structures. I think I need to fit two structures (independent variables) into `X` for it to work.  Is there a way to do it? Perhaps I'm on the wrong track?

Here is what my structs look like:

```
s(1).s1 = -0.169
s(2).s1 = 0.125
s(3).s1 = -0.188
s(4).s1 = 0.188
s(5).s1 = 0.012

s(1).s2 = 0.572
s(2).s2 = 0.300
s(3).s2 = 0.018
s(4).s2 = 0.147
s(5).s2 = 1.080

s(1).s3 = 0.076
s(2).s3 = -0.490
s(3).s3 = -0.144
s(4).s3 = -0.134
s(5).s3 = -0.183
```

`s1` and `s2` are my independent variables and `s3` is the dependent variable.

Comment: `regress` works with matrices and vectors.  I don't understand how you'd want to use this with structures.  What do these structures contain?  Can't you just access the right field and use `regress`?

Comment: I just edited the question and added code with structs. I was not very successful at accessing these structs with regress. Would I need to convert these structs into matrices and vectors somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have your values as fields in a structure array is beyond my understanding.... but working with this, extract out the fields and place them into a matrix (for the independent variables) and a vector (for the dependent variable).

Extract out each field for each structure into a comma-separated list, then use `regress`:

```
X = [[s.s1].' [s.s2].'];
y = [s.s3].';

b = regress(y, X);
```

This is assuming that the first column consists of `s1` and the second column consists of `s2` for the "independent" matrix.  Also, `s3` is the dependent variable.  Simply put, the `X` matrix will consist of two columns.  The first column is all of the `s1` values extracted from the array of structures and the second column is all of the `s2` values extracted.  The dependent vector is made up of all of the `s3` values.  This syntax `[s.s1]` (or `[s.s2]` and `[s.s3]`) may seem a bit peculiar but it is common-place in MATLAB.  Doing `s.s1` for example produces a comma-separated list which takes each field from the array of structures and represents them like so:

```
s(1).s1, s(2).s1, s(3).s1, s(4).s1, s(5).s1
```

Wrapping this with `[]` essentially creates an array, but this creates a **row** vector.  We need to make this a column vector, which is why the transpose (`.'`) operator is required.  For `regress` each column is a variable while each row is a sample for the `X` matrix.  We repeat this for the `s2` field, and the dependent vector for `s3`.

After running this code, I get:

```
>> format long g;
>> b

b =

        -0.687194475280996
         -0.21086419010155
```

`format long g;` is used to show more digits of precision for the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This is just an excerpt from my dataset I use to test my model. Later I will populate it with about 60,000 data points so I thought it would be a good idea to put it all into an array of structures.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov Aha, I see.  How exactly are you loading in the data points in MATLAB?  Would it be prudent to directly store them as a matrix, instead of an array of structures?  I mean no insult or criticism, but this extra level of representation seems redundant.

Comment: BTW, consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help.  Good luck!

Comment: @ArthurTarasov I've added some more explanation on why comma-separated lists are needed here and the syntax I used to solve the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Nice, many thanks! Yeah now I need to think about storing all the data as a matrix. The data is a big heterogeneous so I am afraid I will mix them up without struct names, which I plan to use as labels.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov ah I see.  In that case, consider creating a `table`, then right before you call `regress`, convert the `table` to a matrix via `table2array`.  Something like this will work: `T = table(s1, s2);` assuming that your independent variables are stored in vectors `s1` and `s2`.  You can then display the table by just typing in `T` in the command prompt and pushing ENTER.   You also get to see label information for each variable... then when the time comes, `X = table2array(T);`.